# Extreme points $f(x, y, z)=x^2+y^2-z$ under the condition $2x-3y+z-6=0$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

How to find the extreme points of $f(x, y, z)=x^2+y^2-z$ under the restriction $2x-3y+z-6=0$?

Comment: Are you familiar with Lagrange multipliers? Regardless, can you share your thoughts on the problem and explain what you have tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your objective function is $f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2-z$ and your constraint is $g = 2x-3y+z-6$. The method of Lagrange multipliers says to look for extremal points by studying solutions for the equation $\nabla f = \lambda \nabla g$ subject $g=0$. The reason for this is that the extremal solution gives curves on the constraint whose tangents must be orthogonal to $\nabla f$ and $\nabla g$ hence the gradients must be colinear. You just need to work out the equations implicit within $\nabla f = \lambda \nabla g$ and $g=0$. Since you don't care about $\lambda$ maybe start with eliminating that.

Comment: I find that unique extreme point is $(-1, 3/2, 25/2)$...is correct?

Comment: That's the minimum of the function. This is the only stationary point so the maximum should occur on the boundary, but because there are not restrictions on $x,y,z$ there are no boundaries, so there isn't maximum.

Comment: @RoinerSeguraCubero well, that point is on the plane and it does satisfy the Lagrange multiplier equation so I think you did it right. Note the constraint is not compact so there is no guarantee the min/max exists. That said, Stefan4024 has already suggested the meaning, and his interpretation looks right.